# Is there a notification when a GAE instance is about to be terminated?

Tags: google-app-engine

In a Python Google App Engine environment, I have some highly volatile data which should be eventually saved. I would store it in global variables of an instance, but I need some sort of notice that the instance is being shutdown so I could write it out.

Is there such a callback or place to install a hook?

(memcache is an alternative, but I do not need the overhead of consistency between instances and it also shares the problem of vanishing without warning)

(for more on using global variables one can read about [Cachepy](http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/cachepy-faster-than-memcache-and-unlimited-quota) in the Google Cookbook.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at how [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/gaesessions/__init__.py) works.  It adds a session middleware to the wsgi app so that data is persisted at the end of each request.

You could give each instance a unique id when it starts up, and always write the volatile data to an entity, with that unique id as a key name, at the end of each request.  You would end up doing more writes, but you'd never lose the data to a crashed or terminated instance.  You would never need to read the data into an instance, because it would persist for the instance's lifetime (I think).

Comment: This really has nothing to do with sessions, which are user-facing. What you suggest is equivalent to just storing data in the datastore.

Comment: I was just refering to gae-session as an example of code that writes data at the end of a request. Since there's no notification when an instance dies the best solution would be to always write the instance's data at the end of the request.

Answer (score 1):

GAE provides shutdown handlers for this. Have a look at this section [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/backends/#Go_Shutdown) (in this case for Go)